# Uploadify Multiple instances on same page not working

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I am using following syntax. I have searched around but I haven't been able to resolve the issue. Anyway I have following code in a while loop

```
<input type=\"file\" name=\"bulkupload[]\" id=\"bulkimgupload\" class=\"bulkupload\" prodid=\"$pid\"/>
```

And following is the jquery part

```
    $('.bulkupload').each(function() {
    var $bulkupload = $(this);
    $bulkupload.uploadify({
        'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'bulkupload.php',
        'buttonText':   'Upload Images',
    });
    });
```

Weirdly it only runs for the first instance and shows simple file upload button on all the later ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID should be unique for each input

```
id=\"bulkimgupload_1\" , id=\"bulkimgupload_2\" ...etc
```

Maybe you can append the $pid like

```
id=\"bulkimgupload_$pid\"
```